# Git merge broke remote repo. How do I fix it?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I could really use some help with this. I'm pretty sure I screwed up merging two feature branches for my team's project on Bitbucket into the main branch. Some files have been deleted and the project will no longer compile.

My git client is SourceTree, and I need to know how to fix these merge conflicts. Is there any way to roll back the repo to the state it was in before the merge? If so, I could really use a concise guide to undoing these mistakes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can abort an in-progress merge by using `git merge --abort`.

Comment: How do I do that in sourcetree? I should point out at this stage that my experience with git is extremely limited. I'm only using it because I understand the necessity for source control, and because I'm being forced to, by my lecturer.

Comment: You should become familiar with the `git` command-line tool. It's the interface most people use to interact with `git`, and it is substantially more powerful.

Comment: I have no problems with that. So to help, could you take me through the process of aborting a merge in a remote repository?